# Django relative import

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I am using Python 2.7 and Django 1.8.11.

My project structure is like this:

```
myapp/
    __init__.py
    settings/
        base.py
        settings.py
        __init__.py
    apps/
        __init__.py
        utils/
            __init__.py
            dynsettings.py
```

Here is a part from my `settings.py` file:

```
import os
from ..apps.utils.dynsettings import import_settings
from .base import *
```

`base.py`:

```
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(PROJECT_DIR)

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'apps'))
```

`settings/__init__.py`:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

from .settings import *
```

I receive an error:

```
from ..apps.utils.dynsettings import import_settings
ImportError: No module named apps.utils.dynsettings
```

Why this works for Python3, but does NOT work with Python2?

How do I fix this?

Comment: Do you need to add `from __future__ import absolute_import` to your `settings.py`?

Comment: Frankly speaking, I took this line from another project. I desperately tried to make import working.. Probably it is not needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `settings.py` change to (swap the strings):

```
from .base import *
from utils.dynsettings import import_settings
```

Comment: Thanks dude!! It works now. But why it was working for p3?